# Choosing good keywords with respect to match type "Phrase" only

Tags: google, google-search-console, keywords, seo

How to choose good keywords or phrases with respective to competition, monthly global searches and monthly local searches?

I am using google keyword tool. I am concentrating on Match type : "Phrase".

Is this good enough?

Match Type : "Phrase"
Competition less is at 3%
Monthly Global search is 1600
Monthly local search is 110

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you choose to do with the traffic that you receive. In case of niches like dentists, 100 searches a month can be profitable. But when it comes to earning revenue through ads, its recommended to choose a keyword with more than 1000 local searches.

Also, stop using the "Phrase" searches, and move over to "Exact". Exact means it shall list out the search count for that exact keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Phrase match is indeed the best barometer for basic keyword research. 1600 global monthly searches is great for a first-time SEO project. However, if you are only interested in local search traffic then I would not consider it high-value and you may be disappointed with traffic if this is your primary targeted keyword.

Answer (score 0):

110 local searches is not a lot at all. If you are in the US that would represent searches within the US in English. Even with a few thousand searches monthly unless you are in the top 3 rankings you wont see much traffic at all. 1600 is low, if you target these keywords you'll want to get into the top 3 to see some traffic

Answer (score 0):

See, you do the math here. 110 searches per month translates into less than 4 searches per day. You'd need a CTR of 25% (which is fairly high and can only be done if you are in the top two positions) to get even a single visitor.

You can give this a shot if you are selling a high ticket item in a niche category. Otherwise look at other keywords first.